# ¿Cómo agregar un header.h en Qt creator?

Tags: c++, clase, qt-creator

El profesor nos envió dos archivos de C++ para simular el movimiento de un cuerpo, pero QtCreator no permite compilarlos. ¿Cómo puedo compilar y ejecutar ese main.cpp?

cuerpo.h

```
#ifndef CUERPO_H
#define CUERPO_H
#define GRAV -9.8

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

class Cuerpo{
private:
    float px;
    float py;
    float vx;
    float vy;

public:
    Cuerpo(float px_=0, float py_=0, float vx_=0, float vy_=0);
    void set_body(float px_, float py_, float vx_=0, float vy_=0);
    float get_px();
    float get_py();
    void calc_pos(float dt);
};

#endif
```

main.cpp

```
#include "cuerpo.h"

Cuerpo::Cuerpo(float px_, float py_, float vx_, float vy_):px(px_),py(py_),vx(vx_),vy(vy_)
{

}

void Cuerpo::set_body(float px_, float py_, float vx_, float vy_)
{
   px=px_;
   py=py_;
   vx=vx_;
   vy=vy_;
}

float Cuerpo::get_px()
{
    return px;
}

float Cuerpo::get_py()
{
    return py;
}

//calculates position of the body after dt units of time
void Cuerpo::calc_pos(float dt)
{
    px+=vx*dt;
    py+=vy*dt+GRAV*dt*dt/2;
    vy+=GRAV*dt;
}
```

Con ambos archivos en la carpeta del proyecto, le doy correr y aparecen estos dos errores:
[image: Errores al ejecutar el main.cpp]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La clase que te han mandado se compone de dos ficheros: cabecera e implementación.

La cabecera, que es el que has indicado en tu pregunta, declara el objeto, y el otro fichero incluye la implementación.

Para utilizar estos archivos correctamente has de incluir ambos en el proyecto.

Si los ficheros no los has colocado en la misma carpeta que el main, tendrás que modificar el include para poner la ruta correcta. Otra alternativa es editar a mano el fichero del proyecto para indicar una nueva ruta de inclusión (donde se buscan los includes).

Con estos cambios te debería funcionar todo correctamente.

Un saludo